# Remove flexbox items unwanted space

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have 3 items to show differently for mobile and desktop,

For mobile:
3 items will be showing in full width so that is fine already.

For desktop:
I want section A to be followed by section B immediately vertically,
and section C staying on the right side,
there are some unwanted space for section A.

Mobile:(It works for this code snippet)
[image]
Desktop Expected:
[image]
What I got:
[image]

Here is the code snippets, how to achieve the effect? Thank!

```css
.flex{
  display: flex
}

.flex-col{
  flex-direction: column
}

.bg-blue-50{
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(239 246 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}

.bg-purple-50{
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(250 245 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}

.bg-red-50{
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(254 242 242 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
  .sm\:w-4\/12{
    width: 33.333333%
  }

  .sm\:w-8\/12{
    width: 66.666667%
  }

  .sm\:flex-row{
    flex-direction: row
  }

  .sm\:flex-wrap{
    flex-wrap: wrap
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:flex-wrap">
  <div class="bg-red-50 sm:w-8/12">Section A</div>
  <div class="bg-purple-50 sm:w-4/12">Section B
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-50 sm:w-8/12">Section C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When posting a [repro] pay extra attention to the word **minimal**. There is no reason to post 549 lines of CSS code and expect that others will go through all of that just to help you for free.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong CSS code myself. really appreciate your reminder and help!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with Flexbox without changing the markup where you have to wrap section  A & C in an own container:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:flex-wrap">
  <div class="sm:w-8/12">
    <div class="bg-red-50">Section A</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-50">Section C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-purple-50 sm:w-4/12">Section B Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I would love to use grid/flexbox or even float or other pure css implementation for this case, but with this implementation, I cannot keep the order with Section A->B->C in mobile layout, sorry it seems i didn't mention the actual order in mobile layout